# Cookie Redirect after Second

Tags: php, cookies

i have a little question about a Cookie Script. My actual Cookie Script :

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    header("Location: https://google.de");
} else {
    header("Location: https://bing.de");
}
?>
```

Now I would like to redirect User they don’t have the Cookie to Google.de and the User they already have the Cookie to Bing.de.
My Script only redirect to Google how I can redirect the User they don’t have the Cookie after 10 Second to google and the User they already have the cookie immediately to bing.de ? 
And can I say that the Cookie only exist 1 Week ?

I hope you can help me

Comment: if you want to wait and redirect, you'll need to do it in JS, otherwise your only option is `sleep()`, and that won't help, the user will be waiting an extra 10 seconds without seeing anything. In Js, wait 10 seconds then `window.location.href = 'https://google.de'`

Comment: I assume you're setting the cookie somewhere earlier and you're trying to add a redirect after 10 seconds to ensure the cookie is set... if so, it doesn't work like that. First the server requests that the client stores a cookie then **the next time** the client connects to that server it sends the cookie back up with the request.